# PHP5.6 - Error Access to undeclared static property

Tags: php

In my project I get this error:

> Access to undeclared static property.

The code apparently is correct:

```
<?php
class Session {
    private static $sessionStarted = false;

    public static function init()
    {
        if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
            session_start();
        }

        if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
            self::$sessionStarted = true; // <-- this line causes the error!!!
        }
    }
```

My environment: Windows 10, Windows Bash and Docker php:5.6-apache

Comment: [No problem here](https://eval.in/869515), are you sure there's no typos in your code?

Comment: try to retype `$sessionStarted ` in class and in method `self::$sessionStarted`

Comment: Are you calling this from a derived class? If you are, change the `private` property to `protected`

Comment: The class isn´t derived and the attrib type correct. I belive that is enviromnet´s problem (docker + windows). After reboot docker some times, the bug dissapeared!

Comment: Same problem docker on mac

Comment: @HumbertoRodrigues It may well be an environment problem as I am having it too on CentOS 7, with the same base image as you, php:5.6-apache. The file (https://github.com/hamishcampbell/silverstripe-auth-external/blob/master/code/ExternalAuthenticator.php) looks correct to me at line 832 where I meet the error. The file has been running on my website for 6+ years and it's still running on my Windows development workstation just fine. The only time I get this fatal error is when the website is package in a container (based on that 5.6-apache image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is due to a very specific bug that arises when you have PHP 5.6 running in a docker container with xdebug. See https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/133

I'll quote [the solution](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/133#issuecomment-488030185) here in case that link ever goes down.

In your docker file replace:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.5
```

with

```
RUN BEFORE_PWD=$(pwd) \
    && mkdir -p /opt/xdebug \
    && cd /opt/xdebug \
    && curl -k -L https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/archive/XDEBUG_2_5_5.tar.gz | tar zx \
    && cd xdebug-XDEBUG_2_5_5 \
    && phpize \
    && ./configure --enable-xdebug \
    && make clean \
    && sed -i 's/-O2/-O0/g' Makefile \
    && make \
    # && make test \
    && make install \
    && cd "${BEFORE_PWD}" \
    && rm -r /opt/xdebug
```

You will need to keep the line that usually follows:
`RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`

**Background:**

I encountered the same issue as above, where I had some old PHP 5.6 code that was using a static variable. The code was not changed in 5 years and my docker image was not changed in over a year, but suddenly it was throwing a fatal error when I was step debugging over it. But the code would execute without error when I removed the breakpoint.

After rebuilding my docker image with the fix above, the problem went away.